# Android - Reacting to assist request

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am programming a tiny app which opens the camera as it is opened via assist-request.
In the onCreate method, it simply opens the camera via intent.
But if the app is opened "the regular way" I'd like to display a little instruction instead of the camera.

Is there an easy solution for checking if the app was started by an assist-request?

extract from my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: If you really mean "checking if the activity was started by an assist-request", look at `getIntent().getAction()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it works! Thank you very much! Would you like to answer this question so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to determine which sort of `Intent` was used to start `MainActivity`, use `getIntent().getAction()` and compare it to the possible values (e.g., `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`).